# My site is running really slow now. Was really fast, now lots of members

Tags: performance, joomla, pagespeed, jomsocial

Hey so my site is running pretty slow. page load speed is about 9.5 seconds. It was about 3.5 seconds. But now that my site is being populated it seems to become more sluggish. Here's my site. http://couplecoffee.com I am not a huge Database guru. But any suggestions would be great as far as diagnosing and fixing this issue.

Comment: We can't help if you don't show your code.

Answer (score 2):

It could be down to multiple things:

**Firstly**, You're using the Gantry Framework by Rockettheme which is a rather heavy framework with lots of Javascript

**Secondly**, you're importing multiple jQuery libraries, not to mention also importing jQueryUI AND Bootstrap.js

**Thirdly**, You're using Community Builder which also imports a lot of scripts as it's a very big extension.

You also seem to be loading 2 files:

`cometchatcss.php` and `cometchatcss.php`

Which if you open when inspecting the page, loads the whole site. So it looks like your entire site is having to load 3 times in total.

**Lastly**, your host may not be able to cope with all the executions on your site and therefore you might want to consider upgrading to a more advanced hosting package, something along the lines of a VPS server

Comment: Very nicely investigated... My best bet is cometchat - source of big troubles and vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am not the best when it comes to debugging etc. Cometchat should be fully removed from my site?? I'll go look into it. Thanks again. Hopefully I can get my load times down.